# Properties induced by surjective ring homomorphism between two integral domains

Tags: ideals, integral-domain

Let $f: R \rightarrow S$ be surjective ring homomorphism between two integral domains.

(a) If $R$ satisfies Ascending Chain Condition on Principal Ideals, must $S$ also satisfies Ascending Chain Condition on Principal Ideals?

(b) If every irreducible elements in $R$ is prime, must every irreducible elements in $S$ be prime?

Comment: what do you mean by *irreducible elements*?

Comment: @ucf An element $r$ of a ring is irreducible if it is not $0$ and not a unit and if factorization $r=uv$ implies that $u$ or $v$ is a unit.

Comment: In integral domain, $r$ is said to be irreducible if $r$ is non-zero, non-unit, and cannot be factorized into two non-units.

Comment: $r$ is said to be prime if it is non-zero, non-unit, and $r|ab$ implies $r|a$ or $r|b$. Then, every prime is irreducible.

Comment: Indeed. Every prime is irreducible, but there are rings that contain irreducibles that are not prime.

Comment: [doubt]?  

$k:=\ker f$.  

$S≅R/k$ So there is a $1$-$1$ inclusion preserving correspondence between the *set of ideals of $R$ containing $k$*, and the *set of ideals of $S$*. so (a) proved.  

(b) follows from *"c is irreducible if and only if $(c)$ is maximal in the set of all proper principal ideals of $R$."* (this is Theorem 3.2. of chapter III of the book **ALGEBRA**, _T.W.Hungerford_)  

Am I right?

Comment: @ucf (a) It is true that there is 1-1 inclusion preserving correspondence between set of ideals of $R$ containing $k$ and set of ideals of $S$. However, a principal ideal in $S$ may no correspond to principal ideal in $R$ containing $k$.

Comment: @ucf (b) Why must it be prime? I do not see the argument.

Comment: as Daniel Fischer, egreg and you say this is a  knot. I shared my idea to see if one can use it?